# When mocking, how do I return one of the arguments that was passed in?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I have a class method which I would like to mock and return one of the arguments that was passed in. Something like this in my code:

```
converted_data = Myclass.convert(arg, some_other_arg, data)
```

And in my test I would like to be able to do the following (although this doesn't work).

```
Myclass.should_receive(:convert).with(*args).and_return(args[2])
```

So the method doesn't actually do anything! If I run as written above, I get an error that it doesn't know what args is to return it.

Comment: I think you should insert here the definition of args and error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
@something.should_receive(:method).with(any_args()).and_return { |*args| args }
```

To return a specific argument, pick it from the array within the `and_return` block! So for your example, it would be:

```
Myclass.should_receive(:convert).with(any_args()).and_return { |*args| args[2] }
```

You likely want to do this on an instance of `Myclass`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#and_return` with a block:

```
Myclass.should_receive(:convert).with(*args).and_return {|args| args[2]}
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work either. - undefined local variable or method `args' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x00000008cb56a8>